# Why do I get a NullPointerException from the read.split(",") method when reading in from a text file?

Tags: java

Here is my code to read a text file line per line.

```
    ArrayList<Student> studentCollection = new ArrayList<Student>();
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("StudentAnswers2.txt"));
        String read = null;
        while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            read = in.readLine();
            String[] splited = read.split(",");
            int[] answersTrans = new int[20]; 
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                answersTrans[i] = Integer.parseInt(splited[i+3]); 
            }           
            studentCollection.add(new Student(splited[0], splited[1], splited[2], answersTrans));                  
        }
```

Context: I am trying to set each comma separated value as fields of a List of Student objects ( one line per Student). The first 3 values need to go in as String parameters, and the following 20 values go in as one int[] array.

Here's the content of the txt file:

> C97288501,Byrne,John,0,3,3,0,2,4,0,1,4,5,0,3,3,1,2,4,2,0,4,5
>   D11255403,Smith,Eileen,1,3,2,0,4,3,1,4,5,0,3,3,1,3,4,5,0,5,4,0
>   C06623662,Doyle,Mary,1,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,4,5,3,3,3,5,2,4,2,5,4,5
>   C02887223,Radecki,Jason,2,4,3,0,2,2,4,1,0,2,3,3,5,0,4,4,0,4,0,5
>   D11123581,Hanley,Nora,1,0,2,2,3,0,0,1,5,4,3,3,0,3,2,4,0,5,4,4

Comment: I am not sure if this is exactly a duplicate. The OP is asking why it is being thrown, not what a NPE is. They just don't know why it would be thrown when something is in the file. See @Eran answer

Comment: Thanks, I removed the extra in.readLine() and it works now :)

Comment: You should thank @Eran by giving an upvote and accept his answer (if possible) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the extra `in.readLine()`, since you already read the line in the condition of the while loop. the extra `in.readLine()` causes you to skip every second line, and may cause the following `read.split(",")` to throw `NullPointerException`, since you don't check if it returned null.

```
    while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        read = in.readLine(); // this extra readLine is wrong
                              // and should be removed
```